# Magento 2 backend update attributes on schedule, but never updates

Tags: magento2

I have tried to reindex but product attribute still not updated

Please check screenshot given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you been able to solve this issue? I have the same thing and have not been able to find a solution...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/174692)

Comment: I understand, but I can't add a comment...